# How to emulate mobile performance?

Tags: google-chrome

In Chrome, it's easy to emulate different sizes of tablets and mobiles, but what about emulating the device power and speed?

For example, how will I emulate a web-based game on mobile to see how it would perform in term of speed and performance? is this possible?

Comment: Setup a VM with the appropriate hardware specs. As for actual graphics performance you will have a hard time (probably). There seem to be services available that could support you with this.

Comment: What service that provide this?

Comment: `mobile app development multi platform testing` I didn't check the results in depth. Essentially those services claim to run your app on different mobile platforms so you don't have to own them yourself. Whenever that is true would be a different matter.